# Calling OCX(COM) method using C#

Tags: c#, com, ocx

I am using an OCX library from C#. I have added COM reference from Visual Studio. When I try to create an object in this class I am getting,

```
var ocxCls = new MyOCXClass();

CS1729  'MyOCXClass' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

If I use reflection to see the parameters and constructor count,

```
        Type tt = typeof(MyOCXClass);
        var  flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var cs = tt.GetConstructors(flags)[0].GetParameters().Count();
```

The constructor's count is 1 and parameters 0? What's happening?

**Update:** When I opened OCX inside OLEView I got,

[image]

Comment: _"What's happening?"_ - The wonderful world of OCX. Do you have another source of documentation about this library? Having dealt with OCXs for some time, I can only suggest you avoid them _at all cost_. Yes, _all_.

Comment: @Fildor If I do F12 I can see only `public virtual` members od this OCX class

Comment: But no CTORS other than the default one, right? Or no CTORs at all? And there's no further documentation somewhere on the net?

Comment: Even I don't see any constructor in F12. I see it inherit from 3 interfaces. If I decompile the generated library by Visual Studio, I see `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        internal extern MyOCXClass();`

Comment: Not sure if decompilation works as expected for OCX ... the one I had the misfortune to have to deal with needed a window handle ... if that helps?

Comment: That is [entirely normal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/noncreatable).  If you can't find a factory method in the api then you do have to talk to the author.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, can we somehow see noncreatable in the OCX control

Comment: Use OleView tool from windows SDK on the .tlb aside the OCX or on the OCX file itself (which may contain a TLB embedded) to check attributes like that

Comment: @SimonMourier is there a way to call OCX function/method from C#? I already tried the above approach

Comment: Check what Hans says using OleView. If the coclass is non creatable, there's not much you can do.

Comment: Where I can find oleview? any download link? Do I need to install 2-3 GB for oleview

Comment: It's installed with Visual Studio or Windows SDK (maybe both not sure). Otherwise, you can try this tool http://www.benf.org/other/olewoo/index.html it has some bugs, but maybe sufficient in your case.

Comment: Thanks, OleView was inside VS. I tried opened the OCX inside OleView I got a screen (see updated question)

Comment: Hans and Simon, I was able to call this OCX from WindowsForm. From Windows Form, the generated class has a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the Console application, I have used a WinForm application. Now Visual Studio generates a class that I am able to instantiate.

In Console the class generated was,

```
[ClassInterfaceAttribute(0)]
[ComSourceInterfaces("OCX.__OCX")]
[Guid("SomeGuid")]
[TypeLibType(32)]
public class OCXClass : _OCX, OCX, __OCX_Event
{
    [DispId(1610809349)]
    public virtual void OCXMethod1(ref short milliseconds);
    [DispId(1610809350)]
    public virtual bool OCXMethod2();
}
```

While in WinForms it shows,

```
[Clsid("{SomeGuid}")]
[DesignTimeVisible(true)]
public class OCXClass : OCXClassHost
{
    public OCXClass();
    public virtual void OCXMethod1(ref short milliseconds);
    public virtual bool OCXMethod2();
}
```

When I use JustDeCompile I also see,

```
[ClassInterfaceAttribute(0)]
[ComSourceInterfaces("OCX.__OCX")]
[Guid("SomeGuid")]
[TypeLibType(32)]
public class OCXClass : _OCX, OCX, __OCX_Event
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    internal extern OCXClass();
```

Note the internal extern constructor which I think stopping me to create an object.